# Notes on Sentences

Tags: tikz-styles

I have a sentence like this "पठ् + अ + ति" and I want to add some notes like shown in the attached image. Is there a package for such things or I need to work with Tikz.

Any reference material or help would be appreciated.

[image]

============Edited question based on Solution given by Gonzolo ===========
Here is MWE and the output I am getting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,AutoFakeBold=3.5]{Sanskrit 2003}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122,175,234}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};}
\newcommand\MyNote[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[rectangle callout, fill=myblue,text width=2cm,align=center,font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},#1] at #2 {#3}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

पठ् \tikzmark{a}\qquad + अ + \tikzmark{b} ति ।

\MyNote[callout relative pointer={(0,1)}]{([yshift=-1.5cm]a)}{क्रिया को धारण करता है वह धातु है ।}
\MyNote[callout relative pointer={(0,1)}]{([yshift=-1.5cm]b)}{"अ \& ति" का कर्ता अर्थ को कह रहा है}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of above MWE]

Comment: Aside, content-related (not TeX-related): the whole word पठति is the verb, the पठ् part of it is more properly called the verbal root, or dhātu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `shapes.callouts` library from TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122,175,234}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};}
\newcommand\MyNote[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[rectangle callout, fill=myblue,text width=2cm,align=center,font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},#1] at #2 {#3}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Some \tikzmark{a}text\qquad Some other\tikzmark{b} text

\MyNote[callout relative pointer={(0,1)}]{([yshift=-1.5cm]a)}{some note for the first text}
\MyNote[callout relative pointer={(0,1)}]{([yshift=-1.5cm]b)}{some note for the second text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For details, please see Section **48.7 Callout Shapes**in the PGF manual.

With the `Sanskrit 2003` font used, \sffamily must be removed from the font attributes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,AutoFakeBold=3.5]{Sanskrit 2003}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{122,175,234}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};}
\newcommand\MyNote[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[rectangle callout, fill=myblue,text width=2cm,align=center,font=\color{white},#1] at #2 {#3}; 
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

पठ् \tikzmark{a}\qquad + अ + \tikzmark{b} ति ।

\MyNote[callout relative pointer={(0.6,1)}]{([yshift=-1.65cm,xshift=-1cm]a)}{क्रिया को धारण करता है वह धातु है ।}
\MyNote[callout relative pointer={(-0.5,1)}]{([yshift=-1.65cm,xshift=0.65cm]b)}{"अ \& ति" का कर्ता अर्थ को कह रहा है}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, its great. I do not see Unicde code in the callout box. when I type in English then it works great. Also how can I control the space between two boxes because my text is very close and I want to keep the boxes at decent distance.

Comment: @Raama please edit your question and add a minimal, complete example code showing the relevant settings. In particular, settings used for the non-English language and a concrete example of the text that you want to apply the call-outs to.

Comment: I posted the MWE based on the solution you have given me and the output as well.

Comment: @Raama please see my updated answer. You can play with `xshift`, `yshift` and the coordinate in `callout relative pointer` to place the call-outs at specific positions. For the font, simply remove `\sffamily` from the font attributes.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this very well with TikZ with the callout shapes from the `shapes.callouts` library.

The notes are set as a label with the option `overlay`, so that they do not affect the size of the TikZ picture (we don’t want it to be bigger than the labeled text). For correction of the vertical dimensions the line

```
\path[draw=none] (tikz@callout.north) -- (tikz@callout.south);
```

is added, otherwise it will protrude in the next or the previous line.

I wouldn’t use this in running text but put it in a float or at least the `center` environment.

The base of the callout pointer is as wide as the labeled text (here `is` and `sentence`).

The pointer points to the nearest point on the border of the labeled text, this is achieved with the tricky line

```
tikz@label@post/.append style={/pgf/callout absolute pointer=\tikz@node@at},
```

that makes sure that `\tikz@node@at` is evaluated after it is actually computed.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  Text/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    anchor=base,
    inner xsep=+0pt,
    outer xsep=+0pt,
    outer ysep=+0pt,
    label={[%
      shape=rectangle callout,
      /utils/exec={%
        \pgfpointdiff
          {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{west}}
          {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{east}}},
      callout pointer width/.expanded=\the\pgf@x,
      tikz@label@post/.append style={/pgf/callout absolute pointer=\tikz@node@at},
      alias=tikz@callout]#1}
  },
  label position=below,
  label distance=2ex,
  every label/.style={draw,overlay},
  labels/.style={every label/.append style={#1}}
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\myNote}[3][]{%
  \tikz[baseline,#1]{
    \node[Text={#3}] {#2};
    \path[draw=none] (tikz@callout.north) -- (tikz@callout.south);
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  This \myNote{is}{This is a verb.} a \myNote[label position=above]{sentence}{This is another word.}.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]