# How to overlay a call-out box on text?

Tags: overlays

[image]

I wish to achieve following. There may be many variant of this.

Comment: Have you tried the margin notes?

Comment: Does it have to be a call-out box, or are you looking for any valid method to mark-up a document with comments?

Comment: There is also tikzpagenodes and hyperref.

Comment: Related: [Explanatory bubbles in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83783/13304)

Answer (score 2):

If PDF annotations are okay for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\newcommand*\callout[2]%
{%
  \pdfmarkupcomment[color={ 0.3 0.3 0.3 },opacity=0]{\textbf{#1}}{#2}%
}%
\begin{document}
\callout{If}{If shows the cause ...} it can be detected ...
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Comment: I didn't know this approach.  It's real nice.

Comment: I am sorry pdf notes are not OK. I necessarily want call-out boxes.The call-out box should overlay on text.

Comment: @ShalabhJain: Forever or only when the mouse hovers above the bold text?

Comment: @ShalabhJain For constant overlay you can use FreeText annotations (type=callout). See: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/example.pdf OTOH, these annotaions must be placed by hand on the page and are therefore not very handy!

Comment: @AlexG: I want the callout box to be forever. The pdf output should be what is given in the image.

Comment: @ShalabhJain Then you can maybe tinker something with `Tikz`'s `callout` library! See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146225/tikz-callout-shape-with-arrow or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131012/notes-on-sentences/131013#131013

Comment: @Josef: Thus we've sorted out that this question is a duplicate, after all.